# Replacing laptop power lead with moulded connector

Tags: power-supply, connector, safety

I have a laptop whose power supply consists of two parts: a lead with moulded BS1363 plug (3A fuse) on one end and an IEC C5 connector on the other; and a transformer which takes the C5 connector and outputs low voltage to the laptop.

[image: Current mains cable and transformer]

I would like to replace the mains lead with a single moulded connector which converts a European-compatible socket into a C5 connector.

[image: European plug to C5 converter]

Unlike the existing mains plug, this converter has no fuse. My question is this: is that a safety issue?

As far as I can tell from other questions the fuse is 'only to protect the mains cable'. Someone pointed out the C5 connector itself is only rated to 2.5A (i.e. lower than the 3A fuse), which adds weight to this argument.

Comment: You can't find a converter to go from a UK plug to an IEC plug???

Comment: Just buy a new mains cable with right connectors. There is no fuse in any Schuko plug, that's an UK thing.

Comment: Yes, plug converters and equivalent mains cables exist and are easy to source. I would prefer to use this smaller connector due to space and weight constraints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since that is definitely an internationally compatible power supply, and only the UK puts fuses in their plugs: you're fine.